# Create a scala function to define Gatling HTTP request chains

Tags: scala, performance-testing, scala-collections, gatling

I'm just a newbie in Scala and gatling.

When I define

```
Object A{
  val asset_sort = exec(http("Sort by Displays")
   .get("/data/analytics/reports/")
   .queryParamMap(asset_details_map)
   .queryParam("""sort""", """video_starts""")
   .check(status.is(200)))
  .pause(1)

 val device_sort = and so on ... variables.
}
```

Now I want to create a Scala function which return me different variable by passing certain params.

I tried something like this

```
val asset_sort = generateWebRequest("Sort by Displays", "video_starts", asset_details_map)

  def generateWebRequest(requestName:String, sort:String, queryParamMap:HashMap):ChainBuilder = {

    return exec(http(requestName)
     .get("/data/analytics/reports/")
     .queryParamMap(queryParamMap)
     .queryParam("""sort""", sort)
     .check(status.is(200)))
    .pause(1)
  }
```

But it throws error

```
i_ui\lib\AssetDetail.scala:47: class HashMap takes type parameters
12:50:36.708 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -   def generateWebRequest(requestName:String, sort:String, qu
eryParamMap:HashMap):ChainBuilder = {
12:50:36.710 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to specify precisely HashMap, use the generic parent interface. Also, no need (perhaps) to specify the type of generateWebRequest, let the compiler infer it. And you usually don't have to use `return` in Scala.

```
val asset_sort = generateWebRequest("Sort by Displays", "video_starts", asset_details_map)

def generateWebRequest(requestName:String, sort:String, queryParamMap:Map[String,String]) = {
    exec(http(requestName)
            .get("/data/analytics/reports/")
            .queryParamMap(queryParamMap)
            .queryParam("""sort""", sort)
            .check(status.is(200)))
        .pause(1)
}
```

Comment: :- i have imported io.gatling.core.structure but still I get not found: type ChainBuilder

Comment: perhaps just remove the definition for now and let Scala infer it? See my updated example.

Comment: Still I get method generateWebRequest has return statement; needs result type
   return exec(http(requestName)

Comment: oh, remove return too

Answer (score 1):

The "class HashMap takes type parameters" is very explicit. HashMap is a generic type, that takes 2 type parameters, one for the key type, one for the value type. Try HashMap[String, String].

Comment: I have imported import io.gatling.core.structure and changed function to HashMap[String, String] param but still it throws i_ui\lib\AssetDetail.scala:44: not found: type ChainBuilder
13:37:11.476 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -   def generateWebRequest(requestName:String, sort:String, qu
eryParamMap:HashMap[String, String]):ChainBuilder = {
13:37:11.478 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -
                                     ^
13:37:11.486 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Users\Vertis\Desktop\gatling\user-files\simulations\delph
i_ui\lib\AssetDetail.scala:44: not found: type HashMap

Comment: Which Gatling version do you use?

Comment: I have downloaded continuous integration one from here a day before https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Continuous-Integration

Comment: So no reason your import doesn't work. Could you share a gist of what you've done?